# Can't figure out how to skip query until api request is ready so it doesnt return a undefined variable in apollo useQuery with useSWR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo

I have the following code which hits a user api with useSWR, if I console log the user the first two times it renders undefined. useQuery is complaingng `user.id` is undefined which is true at some point in the render, however I have tried to pass a skip option and it works with passing a skip option for the cookie variable which has a similar problem, either I don't know how to pass two variables to skip, or it can only take one, or it's not working all together.

Here is my code thus far

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const CATALOG_VALUES = gql`
  query GetCatalogValues($id: ID!) {
    findUserByID(id: $id) {
      catalog {
        decor
        clothing
        supplies
        furniture
        _id
      }
      email
    }
  }
`;

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

export default function Welcome() {
  const { data: user, error: userError } = useSWR("/api/user");

  const { data: cookieData, error: cookieError } = useSWR(
    "/api/cookie",
    fetcher
  );

  var cookieBearer = `Bearer ${cookieData}`;

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(CATALOG_VALUES, {
    variables: { id: user.id },
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: cookieBearer,
      },
    },
    skip: !cookieBearer || !user, // I have tried many different things here
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
  console.log(errors);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>{error.message}</p>;
  if (cookieError) return <p>Cookie Error</p>;
  if (!user) return <p>loading</p>;
  if (userError) return <div>failed to load</div>;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Add your Catalog Type Below</h1>
      {user.id}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <h2>Decor</h2>
        <input
          name="Add Form"
          type="radio"
          value="Decor"
          ref={register({ required: true })}
        />

        <div>
          <input type="submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: `!cookieBearer` condition doesn't make sense :p

Comment: oh because it's a string with or without cookieData, so it woudln't skip

Answer (score 0):

Creating a componenet and passing props fixed it

```
const Form = ({ cookieBearer, user }) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(CATALOG_VALUES, {
    variables: { id: user.id },
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: cookieBearer,
      },
    },
  });

  console.log(data);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>{error.message}</p>;

  return <p>hello world</p>;
};
```

```
 {cookieBearer && user && <Form cookieBearer={cookieBearer} user={user} />}
```